# Нужна помощь по написанию небольшой программы

Tags: java

Как мне написать к-л программу с помощью сообщества `stackoverflow` имея минимальные навыки в программировании и принеся пользу сообществу?

Например моя программа должна быть такой:

> Программа должна снимать с экрана скриншот каждые 10 секунд и проверять цвет определенного пикселя скриншота. Если пиксель нужного цвета, то программа нажимает кнопку Enter и прекращает свою работу. Если цвет пикселя не подходит, то программа продолжает каждые 10 секунд снимать скриншот и проверять. После проверки скриншот должен обязательно удаляться.

Я в Java новичок, надеюсь на подробное объяснение того, как это лучше реализовать, 
заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12807482/6275986 || https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-get-the-colour-of-a-screen-pixel/ -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/11442500/6275986 -> System.exit()

Comment: спасибо большое, ввиду неопытности не догадался поискать на английском:)

Comment: Как вариант, посмотрите в сторону AutoIt, к нему также надо поставить библиотеку, которая может скриншоты снимать. Я с помощью этого много лет назад делал бота для фермы в ВК.

Comment: Нет, тут суть в том что я изучаю Java и реализовать соответственно хотел именно на Java. Но уже все получилось, спасибо за совет

Comment: @Вадим, ещё научитесь :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разбейте задачу на части. Например так:

1. Как запустить программу каждые N секунд
2. Как сделать скриншот
3. Как узнать цвет определённого пикселя на картинке
4. Как программно нажать на `Enter`
5. Как удалить картинку

После этого задайте эти вопросы тут. Получите ответы и соедините их вместе - получите нужную программу и пополните интернет полезной многим информацией. В данном же виде вопрос поисковики не смогут проиндексировать так, чтобы люди со схожими проблемами сюда попадали. А мы тут создаём базу данных прикладных решений, а не пишем бесплатно код на заказ.

Итого: одна конкретная проблема - один конкретный вопрос. И заголовки для индексации поисковиками должны быть говорящими, содержащими конкретную прикладную проблему. В нынешнем виде вопрос и заголовок полностью не вписываются в формат сайта

Comment: Мне не и не нужен был код на заказ, а как раз подобный совет, постараюсь впредь избегать таких вопросов) Спасибо за помощь, вроде уже нашел почти все что нужно.